# Getting error while trying to compile a code IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to compile the below code by getting IndentationError: expected an indented block
Can some one help

```
# Online Python compiler (interpreter) to run Python online.
# Write Python 3 code in this online editor and run it.
import urllib,urllib.request,urllib.parse
class SendSms:
def init__(self,mobilenumber,message):
url = "https://www.sms4g.com/smscwebservice_bulk.aspx"
values = {'user' : 'xxx',
'passwd' : 'xxx',
'message' : message,
'mobilenumber':number,
'mtype':'N',
'DR':'Y'
}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Indent all the block under `class`, and double indent your `def init__` function. Also note, your variable `number` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Python is strict about indentation. It should look more like this:

```
import urllib,urllib.request,urllib.parse

class SendSms:
    def init__(self,mobilenumber,message):
        url = "https://www.sms4g.com/smscwebservice_bulk.aspx"
        values = {'user' : 'xxx',
                  'passwd' : 'xxx',
                  'message' : message,
                  'mobilenumber':number,
                  'mtype':'N',
                  'DR':'Y'
                 }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        request = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        print (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Check out the PEP8 guidelines for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In python your code should use indentation to mark blocks.
For eg:

```
if(some_condition):
    a=b+c;
```

Note the indentation after the if statement